# How to resolve error findViewById error in android fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to add recyclerview in my fragment but I'm getting error when I click on navigation drawer item.

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.myapplication.fragment.Books.onCreate(Books.java:45)

How to resolve error or suggest tutorial to load json data in fragment using recyclerview. with click event on recyclerview. on click item open new fragment with data.

This is my code

```
public class Books extends Fragment {

    private BooksModel booksViewModel;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<BooksModel> bookLists;
//    Context context;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBook); //Line 45 Error
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        bookLists = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            BooksModel bookList = new BooksModel(
                    "",
                    "Title " + (i + 1),
                    "This is Auther"
            );

            bookLists.add(bookList);

            adapter = new BooksAdapter(bookLists,this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        booksViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BooksModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_book );
        booksViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate()` runs **before** `onCreateView()`. You should move all of that code to `onViewCreated()`, which passes you the `View` directly (meaning you don't have to call `getView()` at all).

Comment: after move code to onCreateView Method i'm getting this error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.fragment.Books.onCreateView(Books.java:61)

Comment: I didn't say you should move the code to `onCreateView()` - I said to move it to be in the `onViewCreated()` method (which is another method of Fragment).

Comment: @jkdobariya refer to this, for a better understanding of fragment and how to use it. https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle